# Ошибка Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end tag corresponding to start tag b

Tags: python, telegram-bot

ошибка при работе с телеграмм ботом, хочу что б выводилось привет, а после старта появляется ошибка:

```
2022-08-14 14:34:25,969 (__init__.py:986 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Descrip
tion: Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end tag corresponding to start tag b"
2022-08-14 14:34:25,970 (__init__.py:988 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\shlak\UCHOBA\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 977, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
ihelper.py", line 179, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end tag corresponding to start tag b
"
```

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Привет<b>', parse_mode='html')
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя два открывающих тэга `<b>`, после **Привет** нужен закрывающий `</b>`

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "<b>Привет</b>", parse_mode='HTML')

bot.infinity_polling()
```